# Polynomial cases of 0 1 quadratic programm with linear constraints

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, flow-problems, quadratic

A pseudo boolean function f:{0,1}^n-> R is defined as f(x)= x^tQx +cx where 
Q is a symmetric matrix with null elements in the diagonal. Finding the minimum of this function is solvable in polynomial time if all entries are non - positive.
My question is: Remains the problem of finding the minimum polynomial, if we add linear constraints which themselves decribe a flow. More exactly: Each variable in the constraints occurs in exactly two different equalities and one time its coefficient is 1 and one time its coefficient is -1.

Many thanks for response beforehand!

Comment: What do you mean by "finding the minimum polynomial"?  Can you specify the problem more carefully?